# How to access hash of hash within conditional in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

I have a code like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash = (
          'chrX' => {
                      'b' => [
                               '-51811268 210',
                               '-51810794 350',
                               '-51809935 298'
                             ],
                      'f' => [
                               '51929018 210',
                               '51929492 350',
                               '51930351 298'
                             ]
                    }
        );




  foreach my $cnam ( keys %hash  ) {
             my @lpos_f = ();          
             my @lpos_b = ();          



            if ( $hash{$cnam}{"f"} ) {
                @lpos_f = @{ $hash{$cnam}{"f"} }; 
                print "+\n";              
                print Dumper \@lpos_f;    

            }
            elsif ( $hash{$cnam}{"b"} ) {
                @lpos_b = @{ $hash{$cnam}{"b"} }; 
                print "-\n";              
                print Dumper \@lpos_b;    
            }


    }
```

Why it didn't give print output in each ELSIF condition such
that it gives both these.

```
     +
     [
     '51929018 210',
     '51929492 350',
     '51930351 298'
     ];

    -
    ['-51811268 210',
     '-51810794 350',
     '-51809935 298'
    ];
```

Currently It only gives "+" output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `%temp` is not `%hash`. `use strict` would have told you.

Moreover, you cannot get both of `if / else`. Either the condition is true and you get the first part, or it is not and you get the else part. (With `elsif`, the second condition might be not true as well and you get nothing).

Comment: You are right. It didn't print the "-" though? I updated the change.

Comment: You really shouldn't fix the question - it makes the answer irrelevant and of no use to others.